# Uninstall with Powershell not working so hot :(

Tags: powershell

Trying to use the below PS Script to remove an application its not working.... I'll admit I have very little idea of what I'm doing :(

```
$MyApp = new-object

$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product ` -Filter "Name = 'Application'"

$app = Get-WmiObject Win32_Product | where { $_.name -eq "Application" }
$app.Uninstall()
```

I'm stuck at the below  prompt, for context I'm trying to use power shell to silently remove a program from all the endpoints in the land.

```
cmdlet New-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
TypeName:
```

Comment: does it work when you remove the backtick ` after Win32_Product? also delete the whole `$MyApp` line. Also the second line and the third line seem to do the exact same thing?

Comment: I tried that earlier and get the following if i don't make the app                                You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:1
+ $app.Uninstall()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Try only the last two lines. That should work, as long as the application name is correct. Which it does not seem to be according to your Error. run `gwmi win32_product | select Name` to see correct names of your installed products

Answer (score 0):

The following command is incomplete, New-Object requires you to enter a type, for more information about New-Object : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7

**$MyApp = new-object**

Also, you dont need to create an object.

I would use the following script (explanation at the end)

#To see the entire list of applications with names, use :

**Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select Name**

#Enter the name of the application you wish to delete (in between quotes) :

**$NAME = "My Application"**

#Search for the application with the name you entered after $Name =

**$APP = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $NAME}**

#Uninstall that application

**$APP.Uninstall()**

Explanation :

The following stores your application name in a variable, named NAME, which can be used in the next command.

**$NAME = "My Application"**

The following searches your computer for all applications, and searches through all their names for the value stored in $NAME

**$APP = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $NAME}**

Finally, the following command will uninstall the application (if found) from your system :

**$APP.Uninstall()**